# elementHandle.$$(selector) returns strings instead of elementHandles

Tags: puppeteer

According to [the puppeteer docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle), using `elementHandle.$$(selector)` returns an array of ElementHandles, or an empty array.

But my code returns an array of Strings:

```
const table = await frame.$('#ID-rowTable tbody')
console.log('typeof table: ', typeof table); // object; it's an Element Handle
const trs = await table.$$('tr')

for (tr in trs) {
  console.log('tr: ', tr);  // 0, 1, 2, 3... (not even sure why numbers come out...)
  console.log('typeof tr: ', typeof tr); // string
}
```

My guess is that only certain DOM elements can be used as ElementHandles, but I cannot find a list of accepted elements and the documentation does not mention in which case the function `elementHandle.$$(selector)`would return an array of something else than ElementHandles.

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `for .. in` (Object) instead of `for .. of` (Arrays)

```
const table = await frame.$('#ID-rowTable tbody')
console.log('typeof table: ', typeof table); // object; it's an Element Handle
const trs = await table.$$('tr')

for (tr of trs) {
  console.log('tr: ', tr);  // 0, 1, 2, 3... (not even sure why numbers come out...)
  console.log('typeof tr: ', typeof tr); // string
}
```

A more detail explanation of the difference: https://bitsofco.de/for-in-vs-for-of/